# MP4 Posted using FBSDKShareVideoContent on iOS/Objective-C is not visible to anyone but then poster

Tags: ios, facebook, video

This is a very odd problem in my opinion.

I have an app under development that will post video content to the user's FB timeline.  I encode the video as MP4 with AAC audio and post it to the timeline using the FBSDKShareDialog and FBSDKShareVideoContent classes provided by the Facebook iOS SDK.

As far as I can tell, the upload and posting works wonderfully.  When logged into my FB account in a web browser I can see the videos posted from the iOS app just fine on my own timeline.  The very odd problem is that no-one else can see the video (or myself using the "View As" feature in the Privacy Settings menu).  I have my privacy settings set to Public in all areas that I can find.  Others can see both non-video content posts as well as posts of videos posted from the official FaceBook App, INCLUDING videos made by my app. This leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong in the process of sharing the video vs. something wrong with the encoding of the video or some other file related detail.

My code for the actual opening of the FBSDKShareDialog and the eventual posting of the video is:

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc]init];
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoAssetURL;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;
shareDialog.shareContent = content;
shareDialog.delegate = self;
shareDialog.fromViewController =self;
[shareDialog show];
```

I am hoping some kind soul will have some insight into what I am doing wrong.

Much thanks in advance for any consideration you put into this.

Comment: First of all – is your app set to be publicly available yet? (Top of Status&Review tab in app dashboard.)

Comment: It is not.  I guess I was lacking in understanding of the FB App process regarding submission and review.  I will go through that process now and I expect the App will be able to share properly then.  Thank you for this suggestion and I apologize that it ended up being something I likely should have already have known.  If you create an answer with this information and I am able to get the App submitted and reviewed to where I can test this I will happily accept it as correct.

Comment: I am not talking about review, I am just talking about the “do you want to make this app public and available for all users” switch – that has to be set to Yes, otherwise content created through your app will only be visible to people with a role in the app.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  I had thought initially that was going to require the submission and review but actually it only required a few points of additional information that I hadn't yet filled out.  I've done that now and it works great!  Thank you for your help, and please add an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all – is your app set to be publicly available yet? (Top of Status & Review tab in app dashboard.)

There’s a switch saying “do you want to make this app public and available for all users” – that has to be set to Yes, otherwise content created through your app will only be visible to people with a role in the app.